# Combining two fields based on condition

Tags: mongodb

How can I achieve this using aggregation?

Below is my data:

```
{
  "FirstName": null,
  "LastName": "test1",
  "Gender": null,
  "IsActive": true,
},
{
  "FirstName": "test2",
  "LastName": "jagema",
  "Gender": "Female",
  "IsActive": true,
},
```

I want the final OP to be:

```
{
  "FullName": "abiy Jagema",
  "Gender": "Female",
  "IsActive": true,
},
{
  "FullName": Natra,
  "Gender": null,
  "IsActive": true,
},
```

So if both first name and last name exist concat else just set last name to full name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query:

```
db.aggtest.aggregate([ 
    { $match: { IsActive: true } }, 
    { $project: { 
        "_id": 0,
        "Gender": 1, 
        "IsActive": 1, 
        "FullName": { 
           $concat: [ 
              { $ifNull: [ "$FirstName", "" ]}, 
              " ",
              { $ifNull: [ "$LastName", "" ]}
           ]
        } 
    }} 
])
```